# Issue in display high defination url image in universal loader android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, universal-image-loader

Hello friends i want to display slideshow in view pager with universal image loader so i set below code for that

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    ArrayList<ImageData> mList;
    Activity mActivity;


    public ViewPagerAdapter(ActivityGallery fragmentViewGallery,
            ArrayList<ImageData> mArrayListImageDatas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mActivity = fragmentViewGallery;
        mList=mArrayListImageDatas;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        int loader = R.drawable.no_homes;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mActivity);
        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(mActivity);
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(
                Tag.WebApiImageLink
                        + mList.get(position).getImage(), loader, imageView);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;


    }

}
```

**ImageLoader.java**

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
Context mContext;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService; 

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    mContext=context;
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
{ 
    stub_id = loader;
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(loader);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
          int REQUIRED_SIZE=1000;

         int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
         int scale=1;
         while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }



        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u;
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
         memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

public Bitmap roundCornerImage(Bitmap src, float round) {
      // Source image size
      int width = src.getWidth();
      int height = src.getHeight();
      // create result bitmap output
      Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
      // set canvas for painting
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
      canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

      // configure paint
      final Paint paint = new Paint();
      paint.setAntiAlias(true);
      paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

      // configure rectangle for embedding
      final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
      final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

      // draw Round rectangle to canvas
      canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, round, round, paint);

      // create Xfer mode
      paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
      // draw source image to canvas
      canvas.drawBitmap(src, rect, rect, paint);

      // return final image
      return result;
     }


boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
   }

 }
```

**pagerlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

When i run above code high defination image url display as below
[image]

this image size is 1600x1000 but when i run in my device it is getting small so i want to it full screen in my mobile any idea how can i solve this problem ? your all suggestion are appreciable.

Comment: Set `ScaleType="fitXY"` to your `ImageView`

Comment: Change int scale=1; to some other value and check

Comment: M D : if i set ScaleType="fitXY" then sometime low resolution image also comes so they getting very blur in that case